# Second fundamental form is projection of covariant derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry

On a k dimensional submanifold $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, let $x:V\subset \mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a coordinate patch. Write $x(u_1,...,u_n)=(x_1(u_1,...,u_k),...,x_n(u_1,...,u_k))$. Let $X_i = \partial x/ \partial u_i=(\partial x_1/ \partial u_i,...,\partial x_n/ \partial u_i)$ be the i-th coordinate tangent vector field living in the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now I have 2 definitions of the second fundamental form. Fix a normal direction $v$. One is $\mathrm{I\!I}(X_i, X_j)= \langle v,\partial^2x/ \partial u_i\partial u_j\rangle$. Another is $\mathrm{I\!I}(X_i, X_j)= \langle v,\nabla_{X_i}X_j\rangle$, where $\nabla_{X_i}X_j = DX_j(X_i)$ is the Levi-civita connection on $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is the usual derivative. But how are $\partial^2x/ \partial u_i\partial u_j$ and $DX_j(X_i)$ equal? I expand $DX_j(X_i)$ and get a mess of second derivatives of $x$. Or my definitions could be wrong somewhere?

Comment: Recall/Prove it is independent of the extension to a neighbourhood of $x(V)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so abusing notation, we have $\partial_i\partial_j x=\partial_i X_j=\nabla_{\partial_i}X_j=\nabla_{X_i}X_j$ since $\nabla$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is just usual derivative.

Answer (score 1):

The catch is that the usual derivative is taken viewing the vector field as a function on $R^n$, extended to a neighborhood of the point. The derivative can be computed using a curve on M (or on x(V) to be exact). Once we do that it is easy to see the two quantities are equal.